# array_slice, implode, explode, count, for just a string permutation?

Tags: php, string, permutation, reverse, explode

As a beginner in php, I'm in the situation where I have to reverse the followings strings:

1. "secondname firstname" as "firstname secondame",
2. "secondname1 secondname2 firstname" as "firstname secondname1 secondname2"

The code works but it looks like a little bit complicated for such a function.

```
$name = "secondname1 secondname2 firstname";
$split = explode(" ", $name);

$last = count($split);
$firstname = $split[$last -1];
$secondnames = implode(" ",array_slice($split,-$last, $last-1));

echo implode(" ",array($firstname, $secondnames));
```

Do you have any idea about something simpler ?

Comment: No, but you can wrap that block into a function of your own design so you'll only have to write it once. The problem is too specific for a PHP function, but it's exactly the kind of thing you write your own functions for.

Comment: It is already relatively compact for what you are doing. If you have to do it in more than one place wrap it in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `pop` the last element off the end of the array and then `unshift` it back to the beginning:

```
function last_word_first($name) {
    $x = explode(' ', $name);
    array_unshift($x, array_pop($x));
    return implode(' ', $x);
}

echo last_word_first("secondname firstname"), "\n";
echo last_word_first("secondname1 secondname2 firstname"), "\n";
```

Another option is a regular expression:

```
function last_word_first($name) {
    return preg_replace('~(.+)\s+(\S+)$~', "$2 $1", $name);
}
```

On a self-promo note, I've got a library that can do it like this:

```
$x = str($name)->split();
print $x[':-1']->prepend($x[-1])->join(' ');
```